# PHP reading value from Firebase

Tags: php, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to be able to read the database by 'test123', see if it exists. But it keeps returning Naw bool(false) which means it cant find the 'test123'? Is it because of the custom Id?

[image]

Firebase format

```
public function get(String $userId = NULL){
    if (empty($userId) || !isset($userId)) { return FALSE; }

    if ($this->database->getReference($this->dbname)->getSnapshot()->hasChild($userId)){
        echo "yoohoo";
        return $this->database->getReference($this->dbname)->getChild($userId)->getValue();
    } else {
      echo "Naww";
        return FALSE;
    }
}
$users->get('test123');
```

Comment: Unable to understand your question. Please elaborate a bit more and add the expected outcome you want. If you got any error, add that too. (do all this by editing your question itself)

Answer (score 2):

I don't speak PHP well, but this definitely looks wrong:

```
$this->database->getReference($this->dbname)->getSnapshot()->hasChild($userId)
```

First off, we have no idea what `$this->dbname` is, but at first glance it seems you're reading the whole database.

But even if you're just reading the correct node, then this `hasChild($userId)` won't work. This code checks whether the snapshot has a child node whose **key** is equal to the value of `$userId`. That's not what your data shows. Your JSON shows a key `userId`, which has a **value** that you want to be equal to the value of `$userId`. So it'd be something closer to `getSnapshot().getChild('userId').getValue() == $userId`.

But I still doubt this will work, since you don't actually know the full path to the node of the user. In such cases you will need to do a query, in this case on the `userId` property. It'd look something like in [this section of the documentation](https://firebase-php.readthedocs.io/en/latest/realtime-database.html#equalto):

```
$db->getReference('accounts')
    // order the reference's children by the values in the field 'userId'
    ->orderByChild('userId')
    // returns all accounts with the exact userID
    ->equalTo($userId)
    ->getSnapshot();
```