# Update firebase realtime ios database from php

Tags: php, ios, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a created a firebase realtime database and I can get the values from that database to the ios app.

The problem is that the update of the database must be done when a user makes a reservation through a wordpress site.

My question is: Is it possible to update the Firebase IOS database from a .php file or javascript?

If that is not possible, than is it possible that a ios app can read a data from a web app  firebase realtime database ( I have already done this step on android app but with ios seems like impossible)...???

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing iOS specific about a Firebase Realtime Database instance, so you can indeed access that same database from PHP. To do so you can either use the [REST API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/database) that Firebase provides, or you can use a 3rd party wrapper library, such as [`kreait/firebase-php`](https://firebase-php.readthedocs.io/en/stable/realtime-database.html).

Also see:

- [Can we use Firebase Realtime database with core PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48924175/can-we-use-firebase-realtime-database-with-core-php/48968449) (answered by the creator of the library I linked).
- [PHP reading value from Firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56473432/php-reading-value-from-firebase)
- these other [questions about Firebase Realtime Database and PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/firebase-realtime-database+php).